# Why jquery ajax form post not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, firefox

I have used jaquery ajax form post,it works fine in chrome but not in Firefox.
any body please help.

```
    <form id='sig_up' name='sig_up' style='min-width:170px'>
    <textarea id='sig' class='custom-scroll' style='max-height:180px;'></textarea>
    <br>
    <input class='btn' type='submit' /> 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#sig_up').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:  'update_sig.php',
                data: $('#sig_up').serialize(),
                type: 'POST',
                success:function(data){
                    console.log('ok');
                },
                error:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Use JQuery instead of $ sign

Comment: Can you be more descriptive about why it doesn't work in Firefox? Are there errors in the console? Does the request not start? Are the callbacks not called?

Comment: It does not even enter inside submit function. when i type alert('ok'), it never get displayed.

Comment: did you check the console for any errors?

Comment: Does not show any error.

Comment: Debug it. Check whether it go to the 'update_sig.php' file. and Use alerts() if you need.

Comment: And try removing 'e.preventDefault();'

Comment: i tried you code in FF and it worked for me. I just added jquery library. On submit, its firing the ajax call but as the url won't work in my local, it just went to error callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following worked for me:

```
<form id='sig_up' name='sig_up' style='min-width:170px'>
    <textarea id='sig' class='custom-scroll' name="sig" style='max-height:180px;'></textarea>
    <br>
    <input class='btn' type='submit' /> 
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#sig_up').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:  'update_sig.php',
            data: $('#sig_up').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
                success:function(data){
                console.log('ok');
            },
            error:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

A couple of things I did:

1. Added jQuery latest from [Google Hosted Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery)
2. Wrapped JS the code in the document.ready standard
3. The `.serialize()` method only works when you use the `name`
   attribute on form elements. I added this onto the textarea and it passed form data to the ajax file.

Comment: did you test on Firfox 
Samuel Cook ?

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to mention that it does not work from a javascript popup.